# OpenFileDialog: Select Multiple Files Using a Check Box

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

Is there an option to make check boxes appear beside files when multiselecting files using an openfiledialog?

I know that there is a Windows option to change this, but is there a way to temporarily change this for my specific openfiledialog?

Or alternatively is there a way to change the Windows setting? I was thinking I could check to see if its already set to show the check boxes, and if it is I do nothing, otherwise I change it and when the dialog closes I change it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build your own `OpenFileDialog` to achieve this. Create a Class and inherit from `FileDialog`, because `OpenFileDialog` is a `sealed` Class and can not be inherited or extended.

The [`OpenFileDialogEx`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16276/Customizing-OpenFileDialog-in-NET) Project could give you information to implement a nice Solution. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It's not really that important, I just thought it would be a good way of telling users, "hey you can select more than one file!"